# How to Add New Fields on Registration page?

Tags: magento2, custom-field, registration

How to add a new field for the registration page in Magento 2?

[image: Magento 2 company field added]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want add new field, in customer account, you need to override the **register.phtml** in your custom theme.

Create custom theme, then create **register.phtml** in following path

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml**

Then, copy codes, from **module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml** and paste to above created file.

Then, add **your custom field**:

```
<div class="field required">
    <label for="custom_field" class="label"><span><?= __('CustomField') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomField()) ?>" title="<?= __('CustomField') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneStrict':true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Before you do that, you need to create customer attribute for your **custom_field** to store the database.

**Create the Customer Attribute:**

You need to create a custom module to do that, after create Custom Module

Create InstallData.php in following path Vendor\Module\Setup

**InstallData.php**

In this below code I have added **custom_field** attribute.

```
  <?php
  /**
   * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
  namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

  use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

  /**
   * Install data
   * @codeCoverageIgnore
   */
  class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
  {

      /**
       * CustomerSetupFactory
       * @var CustomerSetupFactory
       */
      protected $customerSetupFactory;

      /**
       * $attributeSetFactory
       * @var AttributeSetFactory
       */
      private $attributeSetFactory;

      /**
       * initiate object
       * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
       * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
       */
      public function __construct(
          CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
          AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
      )
      {
          $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
          $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
      }

      /**
       * install data method
       * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
       * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
       */
      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {

          /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
          $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

          $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
          $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

          /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
          $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
          $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
          /**
           * customer registration form default field mobile number
           */
          $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_field', [
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'label' => 'Custom Field',
              'input' => 'text',
              'required' => true,
              'visible' => true,
              'user_defined' => true,
              'sort_order' => 1000,
              'position' => 1000,
              'system' => 0,
          ]);
          //add attribute to attribute set
          $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number')
              ->addData([
                  'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                  'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                  'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
              ]);

          $attribute->save();


      }
  }
```

After that run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

You will see your custom filed in registration form.

Let me know if you have issue.

Comment: In which table save data ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a module and here is `installData.php`:

```
namespace Barcode\Unique\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "barcode_unique");

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "barcode_unique",  array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Barcode",
            "input"    => "text",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => false,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => ""

        ));

        $barcode_unique   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "barcode_unique");

        $barcode_unique = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'barcode_unique');

      $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";

        $barcode_unique->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 1002);

        $barcode_unique->save();

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

This will create field and you can call in phtml( ie :additionalinfocustomer.phtml) file.

You can help from these 2 URL: [IBNAB](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer) and [SASHAS](http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html)

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link to create custom fields on registration page in magento2-

https://github.com/jainmegha5395/custom-fields

This custom module will add custom field and attribute on Registration form. The attribute  will also show in add or edit customer form in Magento 2 Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually let Magento 2 ask the full address on account generation by setting show_address_fields to true in the Register block - then it asks also (besides other's) for the company.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jainmegha5395/custom-fields

This link by Megha Jain has open issues and none answered so I wonder if that should be done or not. It does show the additional field "skype ID" on the form but the point is how do I edit, remove or add new ones.

I wonder why Magento has made it so tiresome to add general registration fields.

Answer (score 0):

**How we can add custom upload field in any like registration and any other custom  form magento 2**