# Magento 2.2.5 - Connect register.phtml to the database

Tags: magento2, database, customer, magento-2.2.5, registration

At the moment I'm struggling with sending data through my register.phtml.

The situation right now is, 
I've created a module that allows me to override the core register.phtml with my own custom register.phtml which contains several fields. Using Pbmage_AttributeManager I've created several customer attributes.

What I am trying to do is, connect the fields that I have made in my custom register.phtml to the attributes that I have created in the database.

I've been looking at the core register.phtml, but I have yet to figure out what their way is of sending data to the database.

Thank you for taking your time reading this.

Comment: have you tried this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2)

Comment: I've used a code similar to that one before, but because it dumps all the attributes under the "additional information" it didn't really work out. Since I'm supposed to follow a certain list, that's why I made a fresh register.phtml so I could edit the title it was under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to show your custom customer attributes inside of the customer registration form. To achieve this, **you don't need to directly modify the register.phtml template** - Magento 2 has much better and flexible solution for this.

All you have to do is to assign the required customer attributes to the **customer forms** you want via UpgradeData script.

You need to do put this part in your UpgradeData.php:

```
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

...

$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
    Customer::ENTITY,
    'your_attribute_code'
);
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create']);
$attribute->save();
```

I've found this in an example there:
https://gist.github.com/zzpaul/bebd89f4665a8ac81db5e3c4ac953ab7

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to make sure, if I were to use the code you provided, would I be able to edit the heading it's under? ex. "Company Information" which has several fields to fill in the attributes under it.

Comment: Sure, you may modify the code in any way

Comment: Where would I do that? And would I be able to add multiple headings?

Comment: Managed to make it work, thank you for the code and example.

Comment: Np, sorry, couldn't answer before on your questions above