# How to add fields to new custom module page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, page, fieldsets, inheritance

[image]
**Here the registration fields**
**i need this fields to new custom module pages 
how to do ??
can i inherit this all fields**

need fields

1.phone no
2.company
3.street address

**note:**
  this all fields attributes are same

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2 . They have created only company fields like that you can create your own fields