# How to find the file in getchildhtml('customer') in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, customer-account, parent-child-theme

**How i find this file and i want to add some fields here**

```
 <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer_form_register_layout3');?>
```

i search in

```
app/design/theme/childtheme/custom module
```

but not found here

how to find `$block->getChildHtml('Cusomer_form_register_layyout3')`

and what is **getChildHtml()**

Comment: search in respective modules layout folder..

Comment: in app/code   or app/design ...

Comment: <referenceBlock name="landingPagelayout3">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register_layout3" template="form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info.layout3" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>

i found i app/code

Comment: I think it's your custom module.so You need to search in app/Code , then if you need to override that xml you have to overwrite it in app/design..

Comment: can i copy that xml to child theme

Comment: yes you can copy that to your child theme

Comment: <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer_form_register_layout3');?>

This code renders 2 fields 

i want to add more fields here how i can do

Comment: Actually it is coming from  form/register.phtml .It will be a form,  so you need to override that phtml file in your theme and extend the fields

Comment: here my question also here      https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263391/how-to-add-fields-to-new-custom-module-page-in-magento-2


how i can override customer registration fileds

Comment: <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer_form_register_layout3');?>

this line where is getting registered fieds

Comment: You need to overide form/register.phtml

Answer (score 2):

```
$block->getChildHtml('Cusomer_form_register_layyout3')
```

- This is nothing but name of block which exist in layout file so you can search in layout(either in your module or design section).
- $block->getChildHtml() used to fetch the content of phtml assigned with respective block name.
- Here is detail description to add one extra tab in product detail page:

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/