# How to add Mobile custom field in Customer Registration Form in magento?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, forms, mobile, customer-registration

How to add Mobile custom field in Customer Registration Form in magento ?

Answer (score 1):

@somutesting

Kindly follow this solution

[How to Add New Fields on Registration page in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2)

Hope this will give you solution.

Comment: please mark the answer if it works for you.