# Magento2: How can I add custom Drop down field in registration form

Tags: magento2, registration, custom-field

I want to add a drop down field (Account type) and get this value in admin just like other fields values.
How can I add custom field in registration form

[image]

Comment: Please follow below tutorials for the same. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2

Answer (score 0):

Steps to add field in registration form:

Step 1: Create field (customer attribute) using `InstallData.php`

```
<?php
namespace <vendor_name>\<module>\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'profile_name', [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Profile Name',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => 0,
            'sort_order' => 110,
            'visible' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 110
        ]);
        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'profile_name');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Step 2: override `form/register.phtml` using layout `customer_account_create.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"><Vendor>_<module>::form/register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 3: `register.phtml`

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('<vendor>\<module>\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra')?>
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset class="fieldset create info">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Personal Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSuccessUrl() ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getErrorUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
            <div class="field choice newsletter">
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
                <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></span></label>
            </div>
            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <!-- Custom code for Profile-Name Field -->
        <div class="field profile-name">
            <label for="profile-name" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Profile Name') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="profile_name" id="profile-name" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getData('profile_name')) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Profile Name') ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="250">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End -->

    </fieldset>
    <?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset address">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Address Information') ?></span></legend><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
            <div class="field company">
                <label for="company" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Company') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field telephone">
                <label for="telephone" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>

            <div class="field street required">
                <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_streetValidationClass ?>">
                    <div class="nested">
                        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                            <div class="field additional">
                                <label class="label" for="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i ?>">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Address') ?></span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address %1', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_streetValidationClass ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field required">
                <label for="city" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field region required">
                <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Please select a region, state or province.') ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field zip required">
                <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field country required">
                <label for="country" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <?php echo $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes');?>
            <?php if ($addressAttributes): ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]');?>
                <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address');?>
                <?php echo $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml()?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        </fieldset>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign-in Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field password required" data-mage-init='{"passwordStrengthIndicator": {}}'>
            <label for="password" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password') ?>"
                       class="input-text"
                       data-password-min-length="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                       data-password-min-character-sets="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                       autocomplete="off">
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" >
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password Strength'); ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label" >
                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('No Password'); ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm Password') ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Create an Account') ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Create an Account') ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Back') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null'; ?>;

    dataForm.mage('validation', {
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                    errorClass = error.prop('class');
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                    .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
    <?php else: ?>
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    <?php endif ?>
    }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

});
</script>
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#country": {
            "regionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? 'true' : 'false'); ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getRegionJson() ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Step 4: Override edit.phtml file using `customer_account_edit.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <!-- Set Custom Template for Register form -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"><vendor>_<Module>::form/edit.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- End -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 5: `form/edit.phtml`

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('\<Vendor>\<Module>\Helper\Data'); ?>
<form class="form form-edit-account" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('customer/account/editPost') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset class="fieldset info">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Account Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getCustomer())->toHtml() ?>

        <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
        <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
        <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_dob->setDate($block->getCustomer()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getCustomer()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_gender->setGender($block->getCustomer()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <!-- Custom Code For Profile-Name Field -->
        <div class="field" data-container="profile-name">
            <?php $linkedinProfile = $block->escapeHtml($_helper->getCustomerAttributeValue($this->getCustomer()->getId(), 'profile_name')); ?>    
            <label class="label" for="profile-name">
                <span>
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Profile Name') ?>
                </span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="profile_name" id="linkedin-profile" data-input="linkedin-profile" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_helper->getCustomerAttributeValue($this->getCustomer()->getId(), 'linkedin_profile')); ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Profile Name') ?>" class="input-file"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End -->    
        <div class="field choice">
            <input type="checkbox" name="change_email" id="change-email" data-role="change-email" value="1" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Email') ?>" class="checkbox" />
            <label class="label" for="change-email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Email') ?></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="field choice">
            <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change-password" data-role="change-password" value="1" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Password') ?>"<?php if ($block->getChangePassword()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
            <label class="label" for="change-password"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Password') ?></span></label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="fieldset password" data-container="change-email-password">
        <legend class="legend"><span data-title="change-email-password"><?php echo __('Change Email and Password') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field email required" data-container="change-email">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="email" data-input="change-email" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field password current required">
            <label class="label" for="current-password"><span><?php echo __('Current Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" class="input-text" name="current_password" id="current-password" data-input="current-password" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field new password required" data-container="new-password" data-mage-init='{"passwordStrengthIndicator": {}}'>
            <label class="label" for="password"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('New Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="password"
                    data-password-min-length="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                    data-password-min-character-sets="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                    data-input="new-password"
                    data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                    autocomplete="off" />
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" >
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?php echo __('Password Strength'); ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label" >
                            <?php echo __('No Password'); ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field confirm password required" data-container="confirm-password">
            <label class="label" for="password-confirmation"><span><?php echo __('Confirm New Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_confirmation" id="password-confirmation"
                    data-input="confirm-password"
                    autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action save primary" title="<?php echo __('Save') ?>"><span><?php echo __('Save') ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?php echo __('Go back') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage"
    ], function($){
        var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
        var ignore = <?php echo $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null'; ?>;

        dataForm.mage('validation', {
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                    var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                        errorClass = error.prop('class');
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                        .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
        <?php else: ?>
            ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
        <?php endif ?>
        });        
    });
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=change-email], [data-role=change-password]": {
            "changeEmailPassword": {
                "titleChangeEmail": "<?php echo __('Change Email') ?>",
                "titleChangePassword": "<?php echo __('Change Password') ?>",
                "titleChangeEmailAndPassword": "<?php echo __('Change Email and Password') ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Step 6: `helper/data.php`

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_customerFactory;

    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCustomerAttributeValue($customerId, $attributeCode)
    {
        $customerObject = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
        return $attribute = ($customerObject->getData($attributeCode)) ? $customerObject->getData($attributeCode): false;
    }
}
```

Done!

Comment: How can we change DOB to be 3 select is that possible