# Magento 2 How to add contact number field in sign up form?

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.1, login-register

I want to add only a `telephone number` add in `register/sign` up form....

So please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to get an answer for a general question like this, do you have some more information about what you exactly want to do ?

How to generally add new fields to the registration form is alerady answered here:
 [How to Add New Fields on Registration page in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2).

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to add a custom field. There is already code but with address fields. But I need an only a telephone number.only one field.

Comment: sadly the phone number in magento2 is linked to an address in the database. So i see generally 2 possibilities. To get into the address creating, to be able to create an address with only a phone number. But i guess the better idea is, to add a new custom attribute for the customer entity.