# Add 1 column on All customer page magento admin

Tags: magento2, customer, admin-panel

I would like to know where can I find the source for this screenshot?

I tried app/code/company/vendor/view/adminhtml/ui_compoment but no luck. I would like to add a column in this page from the database.

Does someone has an idea on this?

Thanks!

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2

Comment: @BalaVaradarajan This is for adding new field not adding column field. I think when it comes to adding columns is with a different approach. By the way, Thanks for this