# Magento 2.3 - How to Add New Fields on Registration page in specific in "Personal Information" section

Tags: magento2

Using Magento 2.3
How to Add New Fields on the Registration page in specific in the "Personal Information" section.
[image]
Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Which field you want to add on Registration page in "Personal Information" section?

Comment: @BhavinPethani I have updated question please check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Add New Fields on Registration page in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2)

Comment: No 'How to Add New Fields on Registration page in magento2? –' here is not full flow. if i flow given flow it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow below step to add custom field on Registration page in "Personal Information" section in magento 2.3

- Override below mention file into your custom module.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

Then add below code into your custom module file register.phtml after line no 18

```
<div class="field field-custom-field required">
        <label class="label" for="customField"><span>Custom Field</span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="customField" name="customField" value="" title="Custom Field" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Please create customer_account_create.xml layout file in your custom module with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
     <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" ifconfig="section/group/enable">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::additional.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

### Please find Custom Field same as below scree-short.

[image]

Comment: I want to Override through module not through the them.

Comment: I am Override through theme, let me override through module and update you soon.

Comment: ok thank you in advance..!

Comment: @vivek i am updated code, please check it.

Comment: @vivek check my updated code which is working for me using custom module in magento 2.3

Comment: @vivek Have you tried my updated code?

Comment: Yes It's working.

Comment: Ok great, Accept my answer if would you like to it's helpfully for other developers.

Comment: Getting error `1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed.`

Answer (score 1):

> Create Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" template="Vendor_Module::register.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Create Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/register.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register $block */
?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra') ?>
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create info">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Personal Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
    <!--    This is your custom field    -->
        <div class="field field-name-custom-field required">
            <label class="label" for="custom_field"><span>Custom Field</span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="custom_field" name="custom_field" value="" title="Custom Field" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name::class)->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()) : ?>
            <div class="field choice newsletter">
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()) : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
                <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?></span></label>
            </div>
            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob::class) ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()) : ?>
            <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat::class) ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()) : ?>
            <?= $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender::class) ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()) : ?>
            <?= $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()) : ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset address">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />

            <?php $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company::class) ?>
            <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()) : ?>
                <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getFormData()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone::class) ?>
            <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()) : ?>
                <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getFormData()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax::class) ?>
            <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()) : ?>
                <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getFormData()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>

            <div class="field street required">
                <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('street') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('street') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                    <div class="nested">
                        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++) : ?>
                            <div class="field additional">
                                <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i)) ?>" id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field required">
                <label for="city" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city') ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>" id="city">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field region required">
                <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="validate-select region_id" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('region')) ?>" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field zip required">
                <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode')) ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field country required">
                <label for="country" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes');?>
            <?php if ($addressAttributes) : ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]');?>
                <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address');?>
                <?= $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        </fieldset>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign-in Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field password required">
            <label for="password" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                       class="input-text"
                       data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                       data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                       autocomplete="off">
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm Password')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Create an Account')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Back')) ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage'
    ], function($){

        var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
        var ignore = <?= /* @noEscape */ $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null' ?>;

        dataForm.mage('validation', {
            <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()) : ?>
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                    var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                        errorClass = error.prop('class');
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                        .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
            <?php else : ?>
            ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
            <?php endif ?>
        }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

    });
</script>
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#country": {
            "regionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getRegionJson() ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?= (int) $block->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".field.password": {
            "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
                "formSelector": "form.form-create-account"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```