# Add company field to Magento registration form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

how to add Company field to Magento 2 registration form https://prnt.sc/u0i06g

Answer (score 0):

Easy way you override your file and change **`register.phtml`**

```
module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml
```

copy your custom theme

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml
```

Then, add your **custom field**:

```
<div class="field required">
    <label for="custom_field" class="label"><span><?= __('CustomField') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomField()) ?>" title="<?= __('CustomField') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneStrict':true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

And you want to custom module. Please check this link :-

**[How to Add New Fields on Registration page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page)**

After that run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**`THANKS.`**